# when to delete the cache entry in django

Tags: python, django, caching

In my django application ,I have a `BlogEntry` which belongs to a `Category`.A `BlogEntry` may belong to many `Category`s

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    creationdate=models.DateField(default=date.today)    
    description=models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    categories=models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
```

A user may edit a `BlogEntry` and in doing so, may remove a `Category` it was in.

Suppose `blogEntry1` belonged to `java,scala` before .If user edits it such that he removes `scala`.Now the entry has only one category ie `java`

In my list_view I am using cache as below

```
from django.core.cache import cache
def list_entries_on_day(request,year,month,day):
    ...
    key = 'entries_day'+'-'+year+'-'+month+'-'+day
    if key not in cache:
        entries = BlogEntry.objects.filter(...args..)
        cache.set(key,entries)
    entries_on_day =cache.get(key)
    ...
```

Suppose I have created 2 entries for today and these are put in cache.If I edit one of these `BlogEnty`s and remove a category 
ie;

```
blogEntry1  has categories :java,scala
blogEntry2 has categories :dotnet,vbasic
```

Initially I make a query for entries for today and put the result in cache

cache now has `[blogEntry1,blogEntry2]` against key `'entries_day-2012-11-11'`

Now I edit `blogEntry1` such that it now has `java` as category

,do I need to remove the stored entries from cache?(Since the cache contains a `BlogEntry` object before it's modification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invalidate cache by registering a signal handler for model.save

You can also live with the fact that users will see the stale content until the cache expiration (1 hour default) make sure he logged in user will not see the cached content, otherwise he will honk the edit was lost.

Hmmm my answer is a bit vague, but I just wanted to say: no, you don't strictly have to invalidate cache at each edit, it is a choice between performance and content freshness.

One more nit: the preferred idiom for cache usage is:

```
entries_on_day = cache.get(key)
if entries_on_day  is None:
    entries_on_day  = BlogEntry.objects.filter(...args..)
    cache.set(key,entries_on_day)
```

You save one cache query